# Scrapy now timesout on a website that used to work well

Tags: scrapy, timeout, request-headers

I'm using scrapy to scrape a website: `https://www.sephora.fr/marques/de-a-a-z/`.
It used to work well a year ago but it now shows an error:

> User timeout caused connection failure: Getting https://www.sephora.fr/robots.txt took longer than 180.0 seconds

It retries for 5 times and then fails completely. I can access the url on chrome but it's not working on scrapy. I've tried using custom user agents and emulating header requests but It still doesn't work.

Below is my code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
import json
import requests
from urllib.parse import parse_qsl, urlencode
import re
from ..pipelines import Pipeline


class SephoraSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    """
    The SephoraSpider object gets you the data on all products hosted on sephora.fr
    """

    name = 'sephora'
    allowed_domains = ['sephora.fr']
    # the url of all the brands
    start_urls = ['https://www.sephora.fr/marques-de-a-a-z/']
    
    custom_settings = {
        'DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT': '180',
    }

    def __init__(self):
        self.base_url = 'https://www.sephora.fr'


    def parse(self, response):
        """
        Parses the response of a webpage we are given when we start crawling the first webpage.
        This method is automatically launched by Scrapy when crawling.
        :param response: the response from the webpage triggered by a get query while crawling.
        A Response object represents an HTTP response, which is usually downloaded (by the Downloader)
        and fed to the Spiders for processing.
        :return: the results of parse_brand().
        :rtype: scrapy.Request()
        """

        # if we are given an url of the brand we are interested in (burberry) we send an http request to them
        if response.url == "https://www.sephora.fr/marques/de-a-a-z/burberry-burb/":
            yield scrapy.Request(url=response.url, callback=self.parse_brand)
        # otherwise it means we are visiting another html object (another brand, a higher level url ...)
        # we call the url back with another method
        else:
            self.log("parse: I just visited: " + response.url)
            urls = response.css('a.sub-category-link::attr(href)').extract()
            if urls:
                for url in urls:
                    yield scrapy.Request(url=self.base_url + url, callback=self.parse_brand)

    ...
```

Scrapy log:

```
(scr_env) antoine.cop1@protonmail.com:~/environment/bass2/scraper (master) $ scrapy crawl sephora
2022-03-13 16:39:19 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.6.1 started (bot: nosetime_scraper)
2022-03-13 16:39:19 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.8.0.0, libxml2 2.9.12, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.6.0, w3lib 1.22.0, Twisted 22.2.0, Python 3.6.9 (default, Dec  8 2021, 21:08:43) - [GCC 8.4.0], pyOpenSSL 22.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1m  14 Dec 2021), cryptography 36.0.1, Platform Linux-5.4.0-1068-aws-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-18.04-bionic
2022-03-13 16:39:19 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'BOT_NAME': 'nosetime_scraper',
 'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 1,
 'COOKIES_ENABLED': False,
 'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 7,
 'DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT': '180',
 'EDITOR': '',
 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'nosetime_scraper.spiders',
 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True,
 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['nosetime_scraper.spiders'],
 'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) '
               'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.95 '
               'Safari/537.36'}
2022-03-13 16:39:19 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.epollreactor.EPollReactor
2022-03-13 16:39:19 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: af81c5b648cc3542
2022-03-13 16:39:19 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2022-03-13 16:39:19 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2022-03-13 16:39:19 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2022-03-13 16:39:19 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2022-03-13 16:39:19 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2022-03-13 16:39:19 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2022-03-13 16:39:19 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2022-03-13 16:40:19 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2022-03-13 16:41:19 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2022-03-13 16:42:19 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2022-03-13 16:42:19 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://www.sephora.fr/robots.txt> (failed 1 times): User timeout caused connection failure: Getting https://www.sephora.fr/robots.txt took longer than 180.0 seconds..
2022-03-13 16:42:19 [py.warnings] WARNING: /home/ubuntu/environment/bass2/scraper/scr_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/engine.py:276: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: Passing a 'spider' argument to ExecutionEngine.download is deprecated
  return self.download(result, spider) if isinstance(result, Request) else result

2022-03-13 16:43:19 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
    current.result, *args, **kwargs
  File "/home/ubuntu/environment/bass2/scraper/scr_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/handlers/http11.py", line 360, in _cb_timeout
    raise TimeoutError(f"Getting {url} took longer than {timeout} seconds.")
twisted.internet.error.TimeoutError: User timeout caused connection failure: Getting https://www.sephora.fr/robots.txt took longer than 180.0 seconds..
2022-03-13 16:49:19 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2022-03-13 16:50:19 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2022-03-13 16:51:19 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2022-03-13 16:51:19 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://www.sephora.fr/marques-de-a-a-z/> (failed 1 times): User timeout caused connection failure: Getting https://www.sephora.fr/marques-de-a-a-z/ took longer than 180.0 seconds..
2022-03-13 16:52:19 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2022-03-13 16:53:19 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2022-03-13 16:54:19 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2022-03-13 16:54:19 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://www.sephora.fr/marques-de-a-a-z/> (failed 2 times): User timeout caused connection failure: Getting https://www.sephora.fr/marques-de-a-a-z/ took longer than 180.0 seconds..
2022-03-13 16:55:19 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2022-03-13 16:56:19 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2022-03-13 16:57:19 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2022-03-13 16:57:19 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] ERROR: Gave up retrying <GET https://www.sephora.fr/marques-de-a-a-z/> (failed 3 times): User timeout caused connection failure: Getting https://www.sephora.fr/marques-de-a-a-z/ took longer than 180.0 seconds..
2022-03-13 16:57:19 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error downloading <GET https://www.sephora.fr/marques-de-a-a-z/>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/environment/bass2/scraper/scr_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1657, in _inlineCallbacks
    cast(Failure, result).throwExceptionIntoGenerator, gen
  File "/home/ubuntu/environment/bass2/scraper/scr_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 62, in run
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/environment/bass2/scraper/scr_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/python/failure.py", line 489, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator
    return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)
  File "/home/ubuntu/environment/bass2/scraper/scr_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/middleware.py", line 49, in process_request
    return (yield download_func(request=request, spider=spider))
  File "/home/ubuntu/environment/bass2/scraper/scr_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 858, in _runCallbacks
    current.result, *args, **kwargs
  File "/home/ubuntu/environment/bass2/scraper/scr_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/handlers/http11.py", line 360, in _cb_timeout
    raise TimeoutError(f"Getting {url} took longer than {timeout} seconds.")
twisted.internet.error.TimeoutError: User timeout caused connection failure: Getting https://www.sephora.fr/marques-de-a-a-z/ took longer than 180.0 seconds..
2022-03-13 16:57:19 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2022-03-13 16:57:19 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/exception_count': 6,
 'downloader/exception_type_count/twisted.internet.error.TimeoutError': 6,
 'downloader/request_bytes': 1881,
 'downloader/request_count': 6,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 6,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 1080.231435,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 13, 16, 57, 19, 904633),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 5,
 'log_count/ERROR': 4,
 'log_count/INFO': 28,
 'log_count/WARNING': 1,
 'memusage/max': 72749056,
 'memusage/startup': 70950912,
 'retry/count': 4,
 'retry/max_reached': 2,
 'retry/reason_count/twisted.internet.error.TimeoutError': 4,
 "robotstxt/exception_count/<class 'twisted.internet.error.TimeoutError'>": 1,
 'robotstxt/request_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 3,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 3,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 3,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 3,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 13, 16, 39, 19, 673198)}
2022-03-13 16:57:19 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

I am going to look at the request headers using fiddler and doing some tests. Maybe Scrapy is sending a `Connection: close` header by default due to which I'm not getting any response from the sephora site ?

Here are the logs when I chose not to respect robots.txt:

```
(scr_env) antoine.cop1@protonmail.com:~/environment/bass2/scraper (master) $ scrapy crawl sephora
2022-03-13 23:23:38 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.6.1 started (bot: nosetime_scraper)
2022-03-13 23:23:38 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.8.0.0, libxml2 2.9.12, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.6.0, w3lib 1.22.0, Twisted 22.2.0, Python 3.6.9 (default, Dec  8 2021, 21:08:43) - [GCC 8.4.0], pyOpenSSL 22.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1m  14 Dec 2021), cryptography 36.0.1, Platform Linux-5.4.0-1068-aws-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-18.04-bionic
2022-03-13 23:23:38 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'BOT_NAME': 'nosetime_scraper',
 'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 1,
 'COOKIES_ENABLED': False,
 'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 7,
 'DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT': '180',
 'EDITOR': '',
 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'nosetime_scraper.spiders',
 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['nosetime_scraper.spiders'],
 'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) '
               'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.95 '
               'Safari/537.36'}
2022-03-13 23:23:38 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.epollreactor.EPollReactor
2022-03-13 23:23:38 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: 3f4205a34aff02c5
2022-03-13 23:23:38 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2022-03-13 23:23:38 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2022-03-13 23:23:38 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2022-03-13 23:23:38 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2022-03-13 23:23:38 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2022-03-13 23:23:38 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2022-03-13 23:23:38 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2022-03-13 23:24:38 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2022-03-13 23:25:38 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2022-03-13 23:26:38 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2022-03-13 23:26:38 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://www.sephora.fr/marques-de-a-a-z/> (failed 1 times): User timeout caused connection failure: Getting https://www.sephora.fr/marques-de-a-a-z/ took longer than 180.0 seconds..
2022-03-13 23:27:38 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2022-03-13 23:28:38 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2022-03-13 23:29:38 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2022-03-13 23:29:38 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://www.sephora.fr/marques-de-a-a-z/> (failed 2 times): User timeout caused connection failure: Getting https://www.sephora.fr/marques-de-a-a-z/ took longer than 180.0 seconds..
2022-03-13 23:30:38 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2022-03-13 23:31:38 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2022-03-13 23:32:38 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2022-03-13 23:32:38 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] ERROR: Gave up retrying <GET https://www.sephora.fr/marques-de-a-a-z/> (failed 3 times): User timeout caused connection failure: Getting https://www.sephora.fr/marques-de-a-a-z/ took longer than 180.0 seconds..
2022-03-13 23:32:38 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error downloading <GET https://www.sephora.fr/marques-de-a-a-z/>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/environment/bass2/scraper/scr_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1657, in _inlineCallbacks
    cast(Failure, result).throwExceptionIntoGenerator, gen
  File "/home/ubuntu/environment/bass2/scraper/scr_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 62, in run
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/environment/bass2/scraper/scr_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/python/failure.py", line 489, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator
    return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)
  File "/home/ubuntu/environment/bass2/scraper/scr_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/middleware.py", line 49, in process_request
    return (yield download_func(request=request, spider=spider))
  File "/home/ubuntu/environment/bass2/scraper/scr_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 858, in _runCallbacks
    current.result, *args, **kwargs
  File "/home/ubuntu/environment/bass2/scraper/scr_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/handlers/http11.py", line 360, in _cb_timeout
    raise TimeoutError(f"Getting {url} took longer than {timeout} seconds.")
twisted.internet.error.TimeoutError: User timeout caused connection failure: Getting https://www.sephora.fr/marques-de-a-a-z/ took longer than 180.0 seconds..
2022-03-13 23:32:39 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2022-03-13 23:32:39 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/exception_count': 3,
 'downloader/exception_type_count/twisted.internet.error.TimeoutError': 3,
 'downloader/request_bytes': 951,
 'downloader/request_count': 3,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 3,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 540.224149,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 13, 23, 32, 39, 59500),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 3,
 'log_count/ERROR': 2,
 'log_count/INFO': 19,
 'memusage/max': 72196096,
 'memusage/startup': 70766592,
 'retry/count': 2,
 'retry/max_reached': 1,
 'retry/reason_count/twisted.internet.error.TimeoutError': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 3,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 3,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 3,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 3,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 13, 23, 23, 38, 835351)}
2022-03-13 23:32:39 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

And here is my environment, `pip list` output:

```
(scr_env) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Work\scrapy-scraper>pip list
Package             Version
------------------- ------------------
async-generator     1.10
attrs               21.4.0
Automat             20.2.0
beautifulsoup4      4.10.0
blis                0.7.5
bs4                 0.0.1
catalogue           2.0.6
certifi             2021.10.8
cffi                1.15.0
charset-normalizer  2.0.12
click               8.0.4
colorama            0.4.4
configparser        5.2.0
constantly          15.1.0
crayons             0.4.0
cryptography        36.0.1
cssselect           1.1.0
cymem               2.0.6
DAWG-Python         0.7.2
docopt              0.6.2
en-core-web-sm      3.2.0
et-xmlfile          1.1.0
geographiclib       1.52
geopy               2.2.0
h11                 0.13.0
h2                  3.2.0
hpack               3.0.0
hyperframe          5.2.0
hyperlink           21.0.0
idna                3.3
incremental         21.3.0
itemadapter         0.4.0
itemloaders         1.0.4
Jinja2              3.0.3
jmespath            0.10.0
langcodes           3.3.0
libretranslatepy    2.1.1
lxml                4.8.0
MarkupSafe          2.1.0
murmurhash          1.0.6
numpy               1.22.2
openpyxl            3.0.9
outcome             1.1.0
packaging           21.3
pandas              1.4.1
parsel              1.6.0
pathy               0.6.1
pip                 22.0.4
preshed             3.0.6
priority            1.3.0
Protego             0.2.1
pyaes               1.6.1
pyasn1              0.4.8
pyasn1-modules      0.2.8
pycparser           2.21
pydantic            1.8.2
PyDispatcher        2.0.5
pymongo             3.11.0
pymorphy2           0.9.1
pymorphy2-dicts-ru  2.4.417127.4579844
pyOpenSSL           22.0.0
pyparsing           3.0.7
PySocks             1.7.1
python-dateutil     2.8.2
pytz                2021.3
queuelib            1.6.2
requests            2.27.1
rsa                 4.8
ru-core-news-md     3.2.0
Scrapy              2.5.1
selenium            4.1.2
service-identity    21.1.0
setuptools          56.0.0
six                 1.16.0
smart-open          5.2.1
sniffio             1.2.0
sortedcontainers    2.4.0
soupsieve           2.3.1
spacy               3.2.2
spacy-legacy        3.0.9
spacy-loggers       1.0.1
srsly               2.4.2
Telethon            1.24.0
thinc               8.0.13
tqdm                4.62.3
translate           3.6.1
trio                0.20.0
trio-websocket      0.9.2
Twisted             22.1.0
twisted-iocpsupport 1.0.2
typer               0.4.0
typing_extensions   4.1.1
urllib3             1.26.8
w3lib               1.22.0
wasabi              0.9.0
webdriver-manager   3.5.3
wsproto             1.0.0
zope.interface      5.4.0
```

With `scrapy runspider sephora.py` I remark it doesn't accept my relative import `from ..pipelines import Pipeline`:

```
(scr_env) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Work\scrapy-scraper\nosetime_scraper\spiders>scrapy runspider sephora.py
2022-03-14 01:00:27 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.5.1 started (bot: nosetime_scraper)
2022-03-14 01:00:27 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.8.0.0, libxml2 2.9.12, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.6.0, w3lib 1.22.0, Twisted 22.1.0, Python 3.
9.6 (tags/v3.9.6:db3ff76, Jun 28 2021, 15:26:21) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 22.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1m  14 Dec 2021), cryptography 36.0.1, Platform
 Windows-10-10.0.19043-SP0
2022-03-14 01:00:27 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.selectreactor.SelectReactor
Usage
=====
  scrapy runspider [options] <spider_file>

runspider: error: Unable to load 'sephora.py': attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Here are my `settings.py`:

```
# Scrapy settings for nosetime_scraper project
#
# For simplicity, this file contains only settings considered important or
# commonly used. You can find more settings consulting the documentation:
#
#     https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html
#     https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html
#     https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html

BOT_NAME = 'nosetime_scraper'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['nosetime_scraper.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'nosetime_scraper.spiders'


# Crawl responsibly by identifying yourself (and your website) on the user-agent
USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.95 Safari/537.36'

# Obey robots.txt rules
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False

# Configure maximum concurrent requests performed by Scrapy (default: 16)
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 1


# Configure a delay for requests for the same website (default: 0)
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#download-delay
# See also autothrottle settings and docs
DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 7
# The download delay setting will honor only one of:
#CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN = 16
#CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP = 16

# Disable cookies (enabled by default)
COOKIES_ENABLED = True

# Disable Telnet Console (enabled by default)
#TELNETCONSOLE_ENABLED = False

# Override the default request headers:
#DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS = {
#   'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
#   'Accept-Language': 'en',
#}

# Enable or disable spider middlewares
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html
#SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
#    'nosetime_scraper.middlewares.NosetimeScraperSpiderMiddleware': 543,
#}

# Enable or disable downloader middlewares
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html
#DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
#    'nosetime_scraper.middlewares.NosetimeScraperDownloaderMiddleware': 543,
#}

# Enable or disable extensions
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html
#EXTENSIONS = {
#    'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole': None,
#}

# Configure item pipelines
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html
#ITEM_PIPELINES = {
#    'nosetime_scraper.pipelines.NosetimeScraperPipeline': 300,
#}

# Enable and configure the AutoThrottle extension (disabled by default)
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/autothrottle.html
#AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED = True
# The initial download delay
#AUTOTHROTTLE_START_DELAY = 5
# The maximum download delay to be set in case of high latencies
#AUTOTHROTTLE_MAX_DELAY = 60
# The average number of requests Scrapy should be sending in parallel to
# each remote server
#AUTOTHROTTLE_TARGET_CONCURRENCY = 1.0
# Enable showing throttling stats for every response received:
#AUTOTHROTTLE_DEBUG = False

# Enable and configure HTTP caching (disabled by default)
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#httpcache-middleware-settings
#HTTPCACHE_ENABLED = True
#HTTPCACHE_EXPIRATION_SECS = 0
#HTTPCACHE_DIR = 'httpcache'
#HTTPCACHE_IGNORE_HTTP_CODES = []
#HTTPCACHE_STORAGE = 'scrapy.extensions.httpcache.FilesystemCacheStorage'
```

Comment: the robots part is simple. You see in your logs there is a 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, go into your scrapy settings and put it to False. Nevertheless, you are still getting timeout for the main url, this can happen for many reasons, the most common one being your IP is blocked because you already scraped the website up to the point they put your current IP on a blacklist.

Comment: Using your code i was able to get all the urls (couldn't go to parse_brand of course since your code doesn't show it here), but everything worked normally.

Comment: Haaa, I remember it used to work even respecting the Robots. I tried using a VPN and an AWS Virtual Machine and none works @Arson0 ...

Comment: I ran your code without even changing the robots thingy and I didn't get a timeout. Yes, countering blocks with proxies and etc is generally the way to go but it seems the problem is not on your code but on your environment!

Comment: Yes, I think you have it right @Arson0 I have added `pip list` and I am now investigating it. Could you share Scrapy version you are using ?

Comment: I thought the same about versioning, but I am using 2.6.1 too.

Comment: The main differences I can see from the way I am running currently and your project is I have cookies enabled and have to use scrapy runspider this_python_file.py instead of crawl

Comment: Just enabled them @Arson0 and tried with runspider without n’y relative import but still have the same error ... I am really puzzled. It’s not even because I run Adblock has it has its own « browser session » ...

Comment: Try using a different connection that has a different IP or use a proxy service. It looks like the IP(s) you are using a hard blocked by the website you are scraping